# How to retrieve rows using select query problem from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Table A has rows with  "FS' and TableB has rows with 'FS' and 'SC'
I need to create a SQL query that can return the row which has FST_SC COLUMN as 'SC' row in TABLE B for the same key for ehich we just have 'FS' records in table A. My requirement is to change RATE for that row in TABLE B to 0 (that I can do after retrieving the row and I know how to do that).

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEA 
(
    CONTRACT TEXT, 
    ID text, 
    CLASS TEXT, 
    ZONE TEXT, 
    CHARGE TEXT, 
    FST_SC TEXT, 
    RATE TEXT, 
    EFFECTIVE_DATE TEXT, 

    PRIMARY KEY (CONTRACT, ID, CLASS, ZONE, CHARGE, FST_SC, RATE, EFFECTIVE_DATE)
);

CREATE TABLE TABLEB 
(
    CONTRACT TEXT, 
    ID text,     
    CLASS TEXT, 
    ZONE TEXT, 
    CHARGE TEXT, 
    FST_SC TEXT, 
    RATE TEXT, 
    EFFECTIVE_DATE TEXT, 

    PRIMARY KEY (CONTRACT, ID, CLASS, ZONE, CHARGE, FST_SC, RATE, EFFECTIVE_DATE)
);
```

TABLEA

```
|MS|US|UE||1|NR|FST|15|09/23/2021|
```

TABLEB

```
|MS|US|UE||1|NR|FST|15|09/23/2021|
|MS|US|UE||1|NR|SC|15|09/23/2021|
```

Desired output:

```
|MS|US|UE||1|NR|SC|15|09/23/2021|
```

This is what I am trying but its giving me 0 rows:
EFFECTIVE_DATE
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FST_SC)=1)
AND FST_ADL_SC = 'SC';

Comment: Please, show your current attempt and describe what is wrong with it. If you have any errors, then post error text as plain text.

Comment: You **SHOULD NOT** use a primary key that contains (almost) **ALL COLUMNS** of a table! That's a horribly bad practice....... and a primary key **MUST NOT EVER** contain huge columns like `TEXT` (or better: `VARCHAR(MAX)` ) - it should be as small as possible

Comment: On an unrelated note, the `TEXT/NTEXT` data types have been on the deprecation list for years, you should be using `VARCHAR(MAX)/NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead. With that being said, you probably shouldn't for the columns you've posted, Zone and Rate look like they should be `INT` and `Effective_Date` should be `DATE`. If you have any control over the schema you should change this sooner rather than later.

Comment: @marc_s - Table is already created, can't help on that.

Comment: @GarethD I agree with you but table is already created, just added here to get an rough idea of structure

Comment: @astentx - Updated question with what I'am trying.  but its giving me 0 rows

Comment: Please add the *whole* query

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLEA 
JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.CONTRACT = TABLEB.CONTRACT 
WHERE TABLEA.FST_SC = 'SC' AND TABLEB.FST_SC = 'SC'
```

Comment: need a row from table B whcih do not have 'SC' row in table A

Comment: Please explain your code (even code comments are helpful).